# Closed questions protected against downvotes?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I explain to newcomers who have their first question closed that this means it's protected against downvotes, but I just downvoted a closed question and the asker did lose 2 rep. What are the consequences of closing exactly?

Comment: Most people will not downvote a close question or open it. On that note, [here are full details](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question/10583#10583). Most poor questions illicit time consuming and missing the original posters point answers. By closing we stop that activity until the question is clear.

Comment: @Kortuk - Would protection against downvotes be a good idea? As a sign to the asker that closing is not just something negative, so that he may be more motivated to mend it.

Comment: this is something that Stackoverflow has dealt with alot and probably has a good stance again. They now have it so a close vote automatically gives a downvote. It is in some way a negative. You have not met our quality guidlines, please fix it. But it can be a positive experience. Remember, our goal is a great database of knowledge, writing a great question means that an answer is not that, just one answer. It means it can answer many questions for people for a long time.

Comment: Again, please feel free to just come to chat and we can discuss more minor things quite easily and when you come to a feature request or such then you can post in meta.

Answer (score 3):

Closing a question doesn't prevent it getting downvotes. If it is a bad question, downvotes are a *good* thing to help focus on useful questions.

If they edit it, it is possible for people to undo their votes. Only "locked" questions prevent votes, but that is a different use-case.

I think the thing you are getting confused over here is that downvoting a question doesn't impact *you, the downvoter*.

Comment: and the fact that in the past I have said I am closing to protect it from downvotes and rude comments. When I close people generally leave it alone.

Comment: @Kortuk that is certainly true - but that is at the psychological/social-engineering level, not at the systems level

Comment: I was just accepting fault.

Comment: it also stops them from being on the main page pretty quickly, correct? That way you do not see many off-topic links and such